# ¿Como puedo hacer para correr una funcion y el app de flask a la vez? en Repl.it

Tags: python, flask

```
import requests
import time
import random

################################################
#   AQUI HACEMOS EL REQUEST HTTP A LA API DE hellcase
#####################################################


def diario():
    url = "https://api.hellcase.com/csgo/es/dailyfree/buy"

    cookies = dict(hellcase_session="cookie de session")

    r = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)

    print(r.text)
    time.sleep(10)



####################################
# SERVIDOR WEB PARA QUE SIEMPRE ESTE ACTIVO
#####################################

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=random.randint(1, 90000))

####################################
# EJECUTAR SIEMPRE diario()
#####################################

while True:
    diario()
```

Es un .py de prueba para ejecutar en repl.it y que me recoja automática la recompensa de una página web. Me inicia el app de flask con la web pero el flujo se corta ahí y no llega al while True, entonces lo que me interesa no funciona.

P.D: El flask lo utilizo por que es un truco para tener la sesión de replit activa. Si hay alguna forma de ejecución de la request HTML 'mas mejor' lo agradecería.

Un saludo.

Comment: no creo que necestes de Flask, simplemente haz `while True: diario()`

Comment: Buenas, el flask lo uso por que lo ejecuto en repl.it y en esta web si no recibe actividad cada x tiempo , cierra la ejecucion. Entonces desde otra web que hace peticiones cada 5 minutos a la web de flask (uptimerobot creo que se llama) lo mantiene activo.

Comment: te recomiendo que para este caso uses Google Colab

Comment: ¿a que te refieres con una recompensa automatica? @ato1905

Comment: @Christian - Con google colab me cierra la sesion, entonces el `diario()` se me cerraria. Igual que repl.it, si sabes alguna 'truquillo' para que no me lo cierren.

Comment: @VictorAlvarado es una recompensa de la pagina: [enlace](http://example.com) _cursiva_  que logeandote cada 24 horas puedes darle click a un boton que te da como un credito, y puedes ir acumulandolo  xD explicacion un poco mala, lo sé y lo siento jajaja

Comment: no entiendo lo que quieres hacer ni cual es el problema real. Si pones un `while True:` la ejecución será infinita (hasta que python te la detanga por seguridad). Si quieres tener un poco más de control podrías usar jupyter notebook o simplemente crear un script y subirlo a un hosting en la nube y tenerlo corriendo como un servicio